# Automate SFTP/SSH prompts on Linux

Tags: linux, ssh, sftp

I'm particularly new to shell scripting and ssh commands and such. I was wondering if I could automate simple sftp prompts when uploading/downloading files from one server to another.

Here is what I do:

- command: sftp username@ServerHost
- Response: The authenticity of host '***' can't be established.
          Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
- after I type 'yes' it asks me the password

I essentially want to automate this since I'll be calling a script which will upload a file from my source server to a remote one through an InfoSphere Datastage sequence job on the source server.

PS. Pardon my insolence if this question doesn't make sense of if it's too juvenile :)

Comment: switch to pubkey authentication.

Comment: Yes, I'm doing that aswell, this is just out of curiosity since I know this method is frowned upon

Answer (score 0):

check out expect, that helps to automate such issues in scripts.

Here a sample that works for me:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set timeout 30

set user "coder"
set node "repohost"
set fsrc "/home/coder/Sources/sysperf/makefile"
set fdst "/tmp"
set uspw "topSecret"

spawn sftp $user@$node:$fsrc $fdst
expect_after eof {exit 1}
expect "$user@$node's password: " {send "$uspw\r"}
expect "*100%*"
```